# Trying to access a diff.exe from a jar

Tags: java, jar, exe

I have a java class in which i am comparing two files, in order to compare i am using diff.exe from DiffUtils 2.8.7
Its working fine when running as a java application

However after creating a jar out of my application and running the jar it doesn't generate any results

Comment: Check your paths... My guess is you have a relative path somewhere and the jar nolonger has the appropriately needed resources.

Answer (score 0):

Check the paths in your call. I bet you don't give the absolute path as parameter. Mateusz.